# Memory Access Violation Reading Location When Calling std::vector::empty()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

The following code causes MSVC to throw an access violation reading location on the stl vector class when calling the method vector::empty. When I look at the data in the vector class it says that it is unable to read the memory regarding the size, capacity, dimensions and "[]" variables and that the raw view is the memory address 0xcdcdcdcd.

```
~Statement_Block(){
    if (!statements.empty()){//throws exception
        for (auto s : statements){
            if (s){
                delete s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern `0xcdcdcdcd` is used by the VS debugger to signify uinitialized memory. So it seems to me that the object being destructed has not been constructed, or has already been destructed once before. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: My guess is that somewhere `Statement_Block` is either being destroyed twice or is not properly initialized (or even not initialized at all). Check your code if this happens. `0xcdcdcdcd` is used by MSVC to mark uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, Another function was returning either a dynamically allocated statement block or a nullptr. Since it was returning a nullptr the program went ahead and deallocated all memory. I made the assumption that all pointers where initialized to nullptr and to 0xcdcdcdcd. As a result when I tested to see if the pointer was pointing to something valid i was testing it against nullptr when it was equal to something else and it tried to delete it and raised an exception.